# jQuery or JS: Select input fields with 2 level brackets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form that adds users to the site, made so you can duplicate the fields to add several users on one go.

So, my  looks like

```
<input name="user[1][name]" value="" />
<input name="user[1][username]" value="" />
<input name="user[1][password]" value="" />
```

And then the number is changed on the duplicated fields, eg:

```
<input name="user[2][name]" value="" />
<input name="user[2][username]" value="" />
<input name="user[2][password]" value="" />
```

and so on.

On PHP I can handle each user since it has it's own array.
But I would like to validate, for example, the username on each user via jQuery.

The closest I got to is

```
$(this).find('input[name="user[][username]"]').each(function() {
```

But for it to work I need to explicitly write the number on the first [], eg:

```
$(this).find('input[name="user[1][username]"]').each(function() {
```

Is there a way to select ALL of them? I tried putting * and * between the [] but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop and not have to write the numbers yourself really easily:

```
var number_of_forms = 3

for(var i=1;i<=number_of_forms;i++){
    $(this).find('input[name="user[' + i + '][username]"]').each(function() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks maxhud. I've tried something like that before but the problem is that I need to specify a max value for the loop :/

Comment: So, every time the user adds a form, you could just execute:    
 number_of_forms += 1 ......

that would automatically increment the max value. just set number_of_forms = 0 and then put that for loop inside a function and call the function when you need it